# Copy data from one sheet and paste that data in all worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet in which formulas are stored now I want that formulas to be copied and paste in all the other worksheets that I have in my workbook

I have such 70 sheets in which data need to be copied.

sheet name from which data will be copied is "SAMPLE"
data should be copied from sheet number 3
("SAMPLE" is sheet number 1 and after leaving 2 sheets, data need to be copy in each sheet in range of "Y1:BA151"

I have tried following code

```
Sub COPY()

 Dim WS_Count As Integer
     Dim I As Integer


     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count


     For I = 1 To 70

       Worksheets("SAMPLE").Range("Y1:BA151").COPY



     Next I

  End Sub
```

but I am begginer so i am lacking somewhere, kindly help with this.
in advance thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop from `3` to the `Count` of the `Worksheets`, and then use `i` within the loop. Or maybe that should be `4`, not sure if I am reading " 'SAMPLE' is sheet number 1 and after leaving 2 sheets" correctly.

```
Sub Copy

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SAMPLE").Range("Y1:BA151").Copy

    Dim i as Long
    For i = 3 to ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
         ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("Y1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```